# ClearDB auto-increment

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, cleardb

I'm using ClearDB to host the MySQL database of my Ruby on Rails application. Today I observed that the id's of the tables, are jumping on steps of 10, starting on 1: 1, 11, 21, 31, 41.. I searched, and found this:

"I'd guess that your auto_increment_increment is set to something else than 1 because of replication. With replicated tables one cannot use 1 because of potential key collisions."

And on the ClearDB forum I found the same answer.. Ok, but the problem is: if id jumps 10 by 10, won't it increases very fast achieving the integer limit of 11 digits very fast? What happens if this situation occurs? The id's go to 2, 12, 22, 32, 42, starting on 2, then on 3..??

Does someone here that uses ClearDB can answer me, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26004621/3067928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID will not wrap around it would conflict with their leader to leader replication scheme.

It does shorten the Id sequence but only by one digit. If your going to have more than 9,999,999,999 rows, then ClearBD is not the plan for you. As your going to hit a lot of their other limits before the row limit.

Comment: What about to put some UPDATE statement after INSERT, changing row_id = row_id - 10? :)

Comment: You can’t change the unique id after creation, the implementation is on purpose to reserve the first digit for database duplication and management inside the ClearDB system.

Comment: I know. You can't change the unique id, but you can change the value after the insert statement. I do that to be more easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this problem you have to upgrade plan, the provided user can not change the environment variable `auto_increment`. After upgrading to super plan, the user can have all the DBA privileges. After upgrading run the query below

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = start_value;