# Auto increment by 1 in MySQL with clearDB

Tags: php, mysql, azure, phpmyadmin, cleardb

I am using Windows Azure with clearDB. Current database auto-increment value is 10. I want it as 1.

I tried to run these commands in PHPMyAdmin with,

**1)**

```
set global auto_increment_increment = 1;
set global auto_increment_offset = 1;
```

**ERROR:** #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

**2)**

```
set auto_increment_increment = 1;
set auto_increment_offset = 1;
```

After that I checked it by this command,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
```

**RESULT:**

```
Variable_name                 Value     
auto_increment_increment      10
auto_increment_offset         1
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: So, you need a `SUPER` privilidged user...

Comment: I am logged in as admin user already in clearDB.

Comment: But you don't have a `SUPER` privilege, which means your admin user isn't all-powerful there. However, take a step back: why do you even _care_ what auto-increment number is used? There's very little reason you should, and those usually mean _upping_ the increment rather then setting it to 1....

Comment: `clearDB` provided us only one username and password. I think it's not privileges based accounts.

Comment: I believe you should create a ticket to clearDB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I submitted ticket to clearDB, They replied me like this:

> ClearDB uses circular replication to provide master-master MySQL support.
>       As such, certain things such as auto_increment keys (or sequences) must be
>       configured in order for one master not to use the same key as the other,
>       in all cases. We do this by configuring MySQL to skip certain keys, and by
>       enforcing MySQL to use a specific offset for each key used.
>       The reason why we use a value of 10 instead of 2 is for future development.

Comment: Great, I thought this step by 10 was about a bad configuration, but now, it makes a lot of sense, thank you very much!